# Resizing controls in WinForm Designer by 32px-steps (VS15)

Tags: c#

I have a little problem with my new custom control. The question is I want it resizes by 32px-steps to create a grid, so I'm looking for an event of post-resizing, or something similar to adjust the control's size. Anyone has some ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just enforce your size requirements:

```
class MyGrid : Control {
    private const int pitch = 32;

    protected override void OnClientSizeChanged(EventArgs e) {
        var w = pitch * ((this.ClientSize.Width + pitch/2) / pitch);
        var h = pitch * ((this.ClientSize.Height + pitch/2) / pitch);
        if (w != this.ClientSize.Width || h != this.ClientSize.Height)
            this.ClientSize = new Size(w, h);
        else base.OnClientSizeChanged(e);
    }
}
```

It is not the most fantastic design-time experience but it is serviceable and very simple since it doesn't require a custom designer.

Do be very careful with this, hard-coding sizes in pixels is not exactly a good idea these days with 4K monitors widely available and costing less than $500.  That 32 px grid cell is going to be but a fleck of dust on such a screen.

Comment: I'm not worried about 4K screens. I have a low resolution and my code is not going to be released.